# Do Basic D&D and 2nd edition AD&D Mystara have separate canon timelines?

Tags: adnd-2e, lore, dnd-becmi, mystara

I've been DMing a 2nd Ed. AD&D Mystara Campaing for a while, but the more I read about the lore of the old suplements from the setting (basic D&D), the more I think the timeline in the 2nd Ed. books are not the same canon as the classic gazetter line of the Known World. Are they separate timelines?

The timeline in the 2nd Ed. books starts in the year 1012DC, where many things are different from de Basic D&D timeline (which starts in the year 1000DC) — things like the fact the The Grand Duchy of Karameikos is already a independent Kingdom, the entire Empire of Aplhatia has sunk into the ocean, and many other minor changes.

My problem is that these changes are only stated in the 2nd Ed. AD&D Mystara line of books, and BECMI D&D sites like the [Vaults of Pandius](http://pandius.com) have kept progressing the lore in the 1000DC timeline. Is each world its own canon timeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they have the same canon but many inconsistency (even inside the same edition).

The 1000-1010DC is a very full decade and Karameikos become a Kingdom in 1006 DC (see *Karameikos - Kingdom of Adventure* pg 21. Before was already indipendent but was named Grand Duchy to count on political support see *GAZ1* pg13). Alphatia sinks in 1009 DC. Read *Wrath of immortals* for more about those years.

Of course (?) the change in edition bring some (many) changes/refactoring, even in history but teorically the canon is the same.

If you read *Poor Wizards Almanac III & Book of Facts*, a chronology for 1012 DC Mystara AD&D2°ed, you'll see that it resume explicitly from *Poor Wizards Almanac II* (and *Poor Wizards Almanac I*) that were for 1010 and 1011 DC Mystara BD&D.